# jqueryui showing hidden tab content on this tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I have an iframe in a tab with a hidden element, and I want to show the element when the tab is opened.

This element (same class) is also under all the tabs, but I only want the element under the current tab to be shown.

Here's my non working attempt at it:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    collapsible: true,
    show: function(event, ui) { 
        ui.find("iframe").contents().find("#hidden").show();
    }
});
```

Corrections would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use ui.panel instead of ui.  The panel attribute on the ui parameter will be the current panel (tab) being shown.

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
        collapsible: true,
        show: function(event, ui) { 
                ui.panel.find("iframe").contents().find("#hidden").show();
        }
});
```